# How to display onbeforeunload dialog when appropriate?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I've got an editor in javascript on my webpage and I would like to ask user if he/she wants to leave the page even if there are unsaved changes.

I know I can add custom message to the "onbeforeunload dialog" this way:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)) but I want to display the dialog only where there really are some unsaved changes. How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var unsavedChanges = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (unsavedChanges) return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}

function makeSomeChange() {
  // do some changes....
  unsavedChanges = true;
}
```

You can make sure to change `unsavedChanges` in the 'change' event handlers.

Comment: It works! I was returning empty string instead of returning null or undefined as you wrote. Thank you!