# How to make conditional stopping and not stopping in $(window).bind('beforeunload')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, onbeforeunload

I have read that if I return something from the beforeunload handler, the browser will show a yes/no dialog with this prompt.  How can this be done conditionally?  For example, if a user has some unsaved data then ask him and if not then don't ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display onbeforeunload dialog when appropriate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663728/how-to-display-onbeforeunload-dialog-when-appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

try this. not tested:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
     if(something){
       if(confirm("Do you want to save before leave the page")){
           return false;
       }
    }

});
```

Comment: Won't work: you can't replace the beforeunload prompt with your own. Returning `false` won't stop the browser from moving away from the page.

Comment: It is said in manual that `unload()` can't prevent the closing, only `beforeunload` can.